# how to convert this array in one?

Tags: json, jq

I am playing around with jq at https://jqplay.org/

The JSON I currently have is :

```
{
  "license": {
    "type": "permissive",
    "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License",
    "name": "MIT"
  },
  "lib": "libxml2",
  "vuln-count": {
    "exact": 2,
    "total": 3,
    "historical": 1
  },
  "vulns": [
    {
      "exact": false,
      "timestamp-objects": [],
      "vuln": {
        "published-epoch": "1072839600",
        "cvss": 9.3,
        "summary": "libxml2, possibly before 2.5.0.\"",
        "published": "2003-12-31T03:00:00",
        "cve": "CVE-2003-1564",
        "modified": "2008-10-24T01:30:02",
        "modified-epoch": "1224811802"
      }
    },
    {
      "exact": true,
      "timestamp-objects": [
        "libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64.cpio:/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.8.0"
      ],
      "vuln": {
        "published-epoch": "1356061574",
        "cvss": 5,
        "summary": "libxml2 before 2.8.0 computes hash values.",
        "published": "2012-12-21T03:46:14",
        "cve": "CVE-2012-0841",
        "modified": "2014-01-28T02:42:55",
        "modified-epoch": "1390876975"
      }
    },
    {
      "exact": true,
      "timestamp-objects": [
        "libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64.cpio:/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.8.0"
      ],
      "vuln": {
        "published-epoch": "1346432101",
        "cvss": 6.8,
        "summary": "libxml2 2.9.0-rc1 and earlier.",
        "published": "2012-08-31T16:55:01",
        "cve": "CVE-2012-2871",
        "modified": "2014-01-28T02:45:36",
        "modified-epoch": "1390877136"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

my current filter is

```
if .["vuln-count"].exact >0 
then {num_of_vulns: .["vuln-count"].exact, lib: .lib, license: .license.type, vuln: .vulns[]|select (.exact==true)|.vuln.cve} 
else empty end
```

And the result is

```
{
  "num_of_vulns": 2,
  "lib": "libxml2",
  "license": "permissive",
  "vuln": "CVE-2012-0841"
}
{
  "num_of_vulns": 2,
  "lib": "libxml2",
  "license": "permissive",
  "vuln": "CVE-2012-2871"
}
```

What is the filter to use in order to get the following output?

```
{
  "num_of_vulns": 2,
  "lib": "libxml2",
  "license": "permissive",
  "vulns": ["CVE-2012-0841", "CVE-2012-2871"]
}
```

Thanks to Santiago, here is the working filter:

```
if .["vuln-count"].exact >0  then {
   num_of_vulns: ."vuln-count".exact,
   lib: .lib,
   license: .license.type,
   vulns: .vulns | map(select(.exact).vuln.cve)
}  else empty end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected result is not meaningful as a JSON! On a JSON object, the property keys must be unique. When property keys are repeated, JSON parsers will usually only keep the last one's value, disregarding the rest.

You can, however, obtain something like this:

```
{
  "num_of_vulns": 2,
  "lib": "libxml2",
  "license": "permissive",
  "vulns": ["CVE-2012-0841", "CVE-2012-2871"]
}
```

Here's a sample script that does so (I omitted your wrapping `if` for empty vulns, but it could be added around it):

```
{
    num_of_vulns: ."vuln-count".exact,
    lib: .lib,
    license: .license.type,
    vulns: .vulns | map(select(.exact).vuln.cve)
}
```

Comment: btw, is the output of jq always a json object?

Comment: @sqr: It doesn't have to, not necessarily. You could return arrays, strings, numbers, or any other valid json value. You could even return the raw values of the strings, provided you use the raw output option.

Comment: jq can output any UTF8 string (or stream of such strings). In particular, it would be possible to output a JSON-like "object" with repeated keys, but whether that would be useful (or wise) is doubtful.